# How to fill missing rows on one table (A) from another table (B) with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am setting up a virtual classroom in PHP and MySQL. This classroom consists of **courses** and each course contains different **subjects or modules**. The student has to examine each module and, finally, a summary (evaluation board) is made to know if the student has passed the course or not.

Having said that, I have a table in which I store the evaluations of each student, in which I keep *inscripcion_id* (student - inscription_id), *modulo_id* (module_id), *fecha* (date_of_examination), *aciertos* (number_of_right_answers), *ultima_convocatoria* (evaluation_last_convocatory) and estado (status).

SQL Fiddle -> [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6369/1/0)

Through some previously established rules that tell me if a student has passed a module or not, I get the following set of data:

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
| inscripcion_id | modulo_id |        fecha        | aciertos | ultima_convocatoria | estado |     ev     |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
|            890 |         1 | 2018-01-24 22:26:09 |        8 |                   2 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            890 |         2 | 2018-01-24 22:36:58 |        3 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            890 |         5 | 2018-01-24 22:38:50 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            890 |         6 | 2018-01-24 22:44:20 |        7 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            891 |         1 | 2018-01-25 09:24:42 |        8 |                   1 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            891 |         2 | 2018-01-25 10:01:55 |        4 |                   8 |      0 | suspendido |
|            891 |         4 | 2018-01-25 10:51:49 |        5 |                   3 |      1 | suspendido |
|            891 |         5 | 2018-01-25 10:23:45 |        9 |                   1 |      1 | aprobado   |
|            891 |         6 | 2018-01-25 11:21:20 |        7 |                   3 |      0 | suspendido |
|            896 |         1 | 2018-01-25 11:55:48 |        1 |                   1 |      1 | suspendido |
|            898 |         1 | 2018-01-25 14:01:51 |        6 |                   1 |      1 | suspendido |
|            907 |         1 | 2018-03-25 16:06:18 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         2 | 2018-03-25 16:07:34 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         3 | 2018-03-25 16:09:04 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         4 | 2018-03-25 16:08:13 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         5 | 2018-03-25 16:10:37 |        2 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
|            907 |         6 | 2018-03-25 16:08:44 |        3 |                   1 |      0 | suspendido |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
```

This data is obtained through the following query:

```
SELECT  e1.inscripcion_id,
        e1.modulo_id,
        e1.fecha,
        e1.aciertos,
        e1.convocatoria AS ultima_convocatoria,
        e1.estado,
        if  (
                ( e1.modulo_id in (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 1)
                    AND e1.aciertos <= 7 )
                OR ( e1.modulo_id = (SELECT modulo.modulo_id FROM modulo WHERE modulo.curso_id = 1 AND modulo.categoria_id = 2)
                    AND e1.aciertos <= 11 ),
                "suspendido",
                "aprobado"
        ) AS ev
FROM    (
            SELECT  inscripcion_id,
                    modulo_id,
                    MAX(convocatoria) AS max_convocatoria
            FROM `evaluacion`
            GROUP BY    inscripcion_id,
                        modulo_id
            ORDER BY    `inscripcion_id` ASC,
                        `modulo_id` ASC,
                        `convocatoria` ASC
) AS e2
INNER JOIN evaluacion AS e1
    ON e1.inscripcion_id = e2.inscripcion_id
    AND e1.modulo_id = e2.modulo_id
    AND e1.convocatoria = e2.max_convocatoria
```

**As you can see, the student 890, has made modules 1, 2, 5 and 6. What I want to achieve is that the modules that are still pending, I also get as a result in the previous data set. The exemplification:**

```
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
| inscripcion_id | modulo_id |        fecha        | aciertos | ultima_convocatoria | estado |     ev     |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
|            890 |         1 | 2018-01-24 22:26:09 | 8        | 2                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            890 |         2 | 2018-01-24 22:36:58 | 3        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            890 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            890 |         4 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            890 |         5 | 2018-01-24 22:38:50 | 3        | 1                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            890 |         6 | 2018-01-24 22:44:20 | 7        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            891 |         1 | 2018-01-25 09:24:42 | 8        | 1                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            891 |         2 | 2018-01-25 10:01:55 | 4        | 8                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            891 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            891 |         4 | 2018-01-25 10:51:49 | 5        | 3                   | 1      | suspendido |
|            891 |         5 | 2018-01-25 10:23:45 | 9        | 1                   | 1      | aprobado   |
|            891 |         6 | 2018-01-25 11:21:20 | 7        | 3                   | 0      | suspendido |
|            896 |         1 | 2018-01-25 11:55:48 | 1        | 1                   | 1      | suspendido |
|            896 |         2 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         3 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         4 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         5 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            896 |         6 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL                | NULL   | pendiente  |
|            ... |           |                     |          |                     |        |            |
+----------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+
```

The result is that the modules that the student has not yet done have been added, with the new value "pending" for the **ev** column.

I have no idea how to do this ... I've tried, I searched the internet and nothing :(

**What is the final objective?** What I want is to obtain a final list with all those students who have the pending course (that is, they have **some** pending module/s), to send them a reminder email that they have to examine themselves of the remaining modules. To those who have approved or suspended, no email will be sent to them.

Can you help me?

SQL Fiddle -> [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6369/1/0)

**THANK YOU VERY MUCH**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to get students with no module in evaluation table as 'pending' like what you provided in the example. The way to get student joining all module is to do a full join on `modulo` and `evaluacion` to get full set of distinct `inscripcion_id` `modulo_id`. Then left join with your existing query will provide the result you want.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6369/30/0)

```
SELECT fs.inscripcion_id, 
       fs.modulo_id, 
       e3.fecha, 
       e3.aciertos, 
       e3.ultima_convocatoria, 
       e3.estado, 
       IF(e3.ev IS NULL, "pendiente", e3.ev) AS ev 
FROM   (SELECT m.modulo_id, 
               e.inscripcion_id 
        FROM   modulo m, 
               evaluacion e 
        GROUP  BY m.modulo_id, 
                  e.inscripcion_id) AS fs 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                                          e1.inscripcion_id, 
                         e1.modulo_id, 
                         e1.fecha, 
                         e1.aciertos, 
                         e1.convocatoria 
                                                            AS 
                                          ultima_convocatoria 
                                          , 
                         e1.estado, 
                         IF (( e1.modulo_id IN (SELECT modulo.modulo_id 
                                                FROM   modulo 
                                                WHERE  modulo.curso_id = 1 
                                                       AND modulo.categoria_id = 
                                                           1) 
                               AND e1.aciertos <= 7 ) 
                              OR ( e1.modulo_id = (SELECT modulo.modulo_id 
                                                   FROM   modulo 
                                                   WHERE 
                                   modulo.curso_id = 1 
                                   AND modulo.categoria_id = 2) 
                                   AND e1.aciertos <= 11 ), "suspendido", 
                         "aprobado") 
                                          AS ev 
                  FROM   (SELECT inscripcion_id, 
                                 modulo_id, 
                                 Max(convocatoria) AS max_convocatoria 
                          FROM   `evaluacion` 
                          GROUP  BY inscripcion_id, 
                                    modulo_id 
                          ORDER  BY `inscripcion_id` ASC, 
                                    `modulo_id` ASC, 
                                    `convocatoria` ASC) AS e2 
                         INNER JOIN evaluacion AS e1 
                                 ON e1.inscripcion_id = e2.inscripcion_id 
                                    AND e1.modulo_id = e2.modulo_id 
                                    AND e1.convocatoria = e2.max_convocatoria) 
                 AS e3 
              ON fs.modulo_id = e3.modulo_id 
                 AND fs.inscripcion_id = e3.inscripcion_id 
ORDER  BY fs.inscripcion_id, 
          fs.modulo_id;
```

For the further question,
You may want to use

```
SELECT inscripcion_id,
    SUM(case when ev = 'aprobado' then 1 else 0 end) as approved_cnt,
    SUM(case when ev = 'suspendido' then 1 else 0 end) as suspended_cnt,
    SUM(case when ev = 'pendiente' then 1 else 0 end) as pending_cnt 
From --the above query...
Group by inscripcion_id
```

to get the count of status for each student, and then do the logic using those count.

Comment: it works like a charm! thanks!!! Can I ask for another tip?? Once I get the result with your query, how do I group the results by 'inscripcion_id', taking into account that I want to analyze the 'ev' field and if there are 5 or more approved modules, then the course is approved, if any of the 6 modules are pending, the final grade remains as pending, and finally, if it has 2 or more modules suspended, the final grade is suspended ... so that once the GROUP BY is applied, the 'ev' field would have the value according to the previous conditions...

Comment: How about 5 modules approved and 1 module is pending? And 2 modules suspended and 4 module is pending? Is your rules have priority?

Comment: the rules are: **if pending module/s** --> final grade = pending // if 5 or more modules aprobed --> final grade = aprobed // if 2 or more modules suspended --> final grade = suspended. /// Following those rules, I can answer your questions as follows: 5 modules approved and 1 pending --> final grade = pending // 2 modules suspended and 4 pending --> final grade = pending. /// The first priority is to check if there is a module pending, then final grade will be pending... **thanks again!!**

Comment: I just saw the further answer. Again thanks! I just tried it and it works perfectly. Now I will try to continue from this. Thanks @samabcde!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1d63/18) 
I wrote the query below, I think it should cover what you want

Notice that you more than one evaluation per module, meaning that you'll get more than one status per module

To solve that, you can add a group statement (in comment now)
Or you the different evaluations to your needs...

```
SELECT
  i.inscripcion_id,
  c.curso_id,
  c.titulo AS curso_titulo,
  m.modulo_id,
  m.titulo AS modulo_titulo,
  IFNULL(ev.estado,0) AS estado,
  m.*
 FROM
   inscripcion i
   INNER JOIN curso c ON c.curso_id = i.curso_id
   INNER JOIN modulo m ON m.curso_id = c.curso_id
   LEFT JOIN evaluacion ev ON ev.modulo_id = m.modulo_id
 WHERE
   (ev.estado = 0 OR ev.estado IS NULL)
/*
GROUP BY
 m.modulo_id
*/
```

;

Comment: Yes, indeed, I've missed a few tables. I thought that for this example weren't relevant. I've tried to replicate your answer, but I've couldn't made it :( Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: you can add them to the queation description and to the sqlfiddle, can be easier to answer

Comment: I only see the 2 tables modulo and evaluacion... am I missing something ? is there a new sqlfiddle link ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the changes have not been saved in the other link :( There's the new link --> [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1d63/2)

Comment: thanks again for your time, but sadly, that is not the result I'm looking for :( nevermind, @samabcde got the result